# Java 24-h string to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, parsing, datetime

I want to convert a 24 hour string ex: `13:05 2017-03-19` to a ZonedDateTime. Currently I'm trying to do it this way:

```
DateTimeFormatter zoneParser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
this.startZoneTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date + " " +start, zoneParser).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
this.endZoneTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date + " " + end, zoneParser).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

But get a parse exception.

Comment: 1. The pattern has no sense with your example / 2. what is 'start', 'end' ?

Comment: For clarity and simplicity I'd parse the three strings, `date`, `start` and `end` individually and then combine into two `LocalDateTime` objects. Finally convert to `ZonedDateTime`, of course.

Comment: As @azro probably hinted at, this isn’t clear. If you would [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we could help you better and more precisely with what went wrong. Also remember to include stacktrace.

Comment: I'm so sorry about the lack of information, I completely rushed posting this question and forgot to change variable names so that they better represented what I was trying to achieve. 'start' and 'end' are the start time and end time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`13:05 2017-03-19` has a pattern of `HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd`, not `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` as you've used - so this will throw an exception if you try to use it with your above code. The pattern must match the format of the string that you pass in.

I've no idea what the `date + " " + start` references as you don't include that in your question, but the following, based on your code, should run without any issue:

```
    String date = "13:05 2017-03-19";
    DateTimeFormatter zoneParser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd");
    this.startZoneTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, zoneParser).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    this.endZoneTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, zoneParser).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I guess I was first trying to convert it into 12 hour time and then into zoneDateTime as I thought it would not convert it otherwise. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @BrijPatel No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    String dateString = "2017-03-19";
    String startTimeString = "13:05";
    String endTimeString = "15:25";

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString);
    ZonedDateTime startDateTime = date.atTime(LocalTime.parse(startTimeString)).atZone(zone);
    ZonedDateTime endDateTime = date.atTime(LocalTime.parse(endTimeString)).atZone(zone);

    System.out.println("Start " + startDateTime);
    System.out.println("End   " + endDateTime);
```

Output in my timezone:

```
Start 2017-03-19T13:05+01:00[Europe/Copenhagen]
End   2017-03-19T15:25+01:00[Europe/Copenhagen]
```

No explicit formatters needed.